# Enforce uniqueness on combination of columns + aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a SQL Server database with the following tables:

[image]

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rule]
    (
        [RuleId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Value1] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Value2] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Value3] [int] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Rule] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RuleId] ASC)
     )
     GO
    
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Type]
    (
        [TypeId] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Type] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TypeId] ASC)
    )
    GO
    
     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RuleType]
     (
        [RuleId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [TypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_RuleType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RuleId] ASC,  [TypeId] ASC)
    )
    GO
    
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RuleType]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_RuleType_Type] FOREIGN KEY([TypeId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Type] ([TypeId])
    GO
    
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RuleType] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RuleType_Type]
    GO
    
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RuleType]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_RuleType_Rule] FOREIGN KEY([RuleId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Rule] ([RuleId])
    GO
    
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RuleType] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RuleType_Rule]
    GO

/*Test data*/
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Type] ([Description]) VALUES ('Type1'), ('Type2'), ('Type3');
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rule] ([Value1], [Value2], [Value3]) VALUES (1,1,1), (2,2,2), (3,3,3);
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[RuleType] ([RuleId], [TypeId]) VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3);
GO
```

The following stored procedure returns all the rules and an aggregate value of their associated types:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SelectRules
AS

    SELECT 
        R.[RuleId], 
        R.[Value1], 
        R.[Value2], 
        R.[Value3],
        [AssoctiatedTypes]  = STRING_AGG(RT.TypeId, ', ')
    FROM
        [dbo].[Rule] R
    LEFT JOIN
        [dbo].[RuleType] RT ON RT.RuleId = R.RuleId
    GROUP BY
        R.[RuleId], 
        R.[Value1], 
        R.[Value2], 
        R.[Value3]
GO
```

[image]

**Question:**

Is there a way to enforce uniqueness on the combination Value1, Value2, Value3 and AssociatedTypes?

What I need to prevent is the creation of a new rule with the same values (Value1, Value2 and Value3) and the same associated types as an existing rule. The same enforcement should apply for updating an existing rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [@SQLpro's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/337699/220697) isn't going to work, because `STRING_AGG` is not supported in Indexed Views.

You can instead use a trigger to enforce this, by storing the aggregated `TypeId` back into `Rule` and adding a `UNIQUE` constraint on it.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Rule]
ADD AllTypeIds varchar(1600) NULL;
```

Insert your aggregated data, and add a unique constraint

```
WITH Aggregated AS (
    SELECT
      rt.RuleId, 
      STRING_AGG(CAST(rt.TypeId AS varchar(12)), '|')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rt.TypeId) AS AllTypeIds
    FROM dbo.RuleType rt ON rt.RuleId = cr.RuleId
    GROUP BY
      rt.RuleId
)
UPDATE r
SET AllTypeIds = a.AllTypeIds
FROM dbo.[Rule] r
JOIN Aggregated a ON a.RuleId = r.RuleId

ALTER TABLE dbo.[Rule]
ADD CONSTRAINT RuleMustBeUniqueValuesAndTypes UNIQUE (Value1, Value2, Value3, AllTypeIds);
```

And the trigger logic is as follows:

- Take the `inserted` and `deleted` tables and union them together to get unique changed `RuleId`
- Left-join that to `RuleType`
- Aggregate by `RuleId` and get all `TypeId` values.
- Join back to `Rule` and update the column.
- If there is a duplicate set then the unique constraint will throw an error.
- Note that we need to take into account updates and deletes as well, because you could *remove* rows from a set and make it clash with another set.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER RuleType_UniqueRule
ON dbo.RuleType
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    RETURN;

SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH ChangedRule AS (
    SELECT i.RuleId
    FROM inserted i
  
    UNION
  
    SELECT d.RuleId
    FROM deleted d
),
Aggregated AS (
    SELECT
      cr.RuleId, 
      STRING_AGG(CAST(rt.TypeId AS varchar(12)), '|')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rt.TypeId) AS AllTypeIds
    FROM ChangedRule cr
    LEFT JOIN dbo.RuleType rt ON rt.RuleId = cr.RuleId
    GROUP BY
      cr.RuleId
)
UPDATE r
SET AllTypeIds = a.AllTypeIds
FROM dbo.[Rule] r WITH (SERIALIZABLE)
JOIN Aggregated a ON a.RuleId = r.RuleId
WHERE r.AllTypeIds IS DISTINCT FROM a.AllTypeIds;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/G-RfmOLU)

Further notes:

- The maximum size for a unique constraint is 1700 bytes, so we limit the column to `varchar(1600)`. A larger aggregation will fail with a truncation error.
- If you need it to be wider than that then you could gain a bit by using `varbinary` and some kind of bit-packing algorithm. Anything much larger will need a completely different solution.
- `NULL` values are also considered unique, so you couldn't have multiple `Rule`s with *no* `TypeId` at all. If this is not desired then change your constraint to a filtered unique index.

  ```
  CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX RuleMustBeUniqueValuesAndTypes ON dbo.[Rule]
  (Value1, Value2, Value3, AllTypeIds)
  WHERE (AllTypeIds IS NOT NULL);
  ```

Comment: Thank you, Charlieface! Your solution worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

SQLpro suggests a nice answer but the outer join/aggregate does not allow it as far as I can tell.

As an alternative, you can:

1. Create a unique constraint on Rule on values 1,2,3 and Rule ID.
2. Create a unique constraint on RuleType so no rule types can have the
   same definition.

I think that will do it so long as 2) is tolerable.

Answer (score -2):

As uniqueness can't be unique when values are NULL, you can create an indexed view with a UNIQUE CLUSTERED index like :

```
CREATE VIEW V_RULES
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT R.RuleId, 
       R.Value1, 
       R.Value2, 
       R.Value3,
       STRING_AGG(RT.TypeId, ', ') AS AssoctiatedTypes 
FROM   dbo.Rule R
       INNER JOIN dbo.RuleType RT 
          ON RT.RuleId = R.RuleId
GROUP  BY R.RuleId, 
       R.Value1, 
       R.Value2, 
       R.Value3;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX X_V 
   ON V_RULES (R.Value1, R.Value2, R.Value3, AssoctiatedTypes);
GO
```

Comment: Does this work?  I can't create an index on a view with string_agg

Comment: You are right, I am wrong.... STRING_AGG won't work with indexed views...

Comment: Even if it did you would need a deterministic ordering for STRING_AGG, as an example '1,2' <> '2,1'

Comment: This is possible in SQL Server 2022 with the WITHIN GROUP clause